# How do you get entry's data from Ajax form submission with Guest plugin?

Tags: guest-entries

I'm trying to get some info from entry like entry ID that the Guest plugin sent it via Ajax. [There are the keys](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries#submitting-via-ajax) that the plugin responds back with. How can I work out to those keys respectively call them? `(response.id)` for example?

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve the data returned from the AJAX call?

Comment: Yes @StephenLewis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the README](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries/blob/master/README.md), the Guest Entries plugin accepts an AJAX request, and returns an object containing the entry ID, title, and so forth.

As such, if you're [using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you should be able to do something like this (not tested):

```
$.ajax({
    data: $('#theform').serialize(),
    method: 'POST',
    done: function (data) {
        // The entry title.
        console.log(data.title);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure how Guest Entries handles errors, so you'll probably want to check the `data.success` property, before proceeding.

Comment: I've ended up calling for entry's data with jQuery `response` function and so on as you've indicated for checking errors. That worked well!